# Is it proper to say, "This is my Uncle Archie's current wife."

Tags: word-usage, politeness

He is on his 4th wife.  Is it proper to say, "This is my Uncle Archie's current wife."

Comment: “current” is unnecessary; it’s just “wife”.  Any previous wives are  *ex-wives*

Comment: This locution might be awkward depending on the reasons that Uncle Archie is no longer is married to the previous three.

Comment: “current” in this case would sound condescending- as if to say “and she won’t be the last”

Comment: Sure. If you want to say that your uncle changes wives like the direction of the wind changes.

Comment: Be prepared for people who seem confused becaause last year your wife was five inches shorter and blonde.  All you have to sa y is "Oh that was Lily.  This is Marigold.:

Comment: Of course, but only if you add, "He married her because she's got a lot of money and a big ass."

Answer (score 6):

Depends on what you mean by "proper". It's perfectly **grammatical** to describe someone as "the current wife of so-and-so". It is not, however, particularly **polite**. It might be OK to describe her as "current" in a conversation that does not include either her or her husband (perhaps when you're showing pictures from the family reunion to Archie's ex-wife number two), but to introduce her as "current" is to, essentially, say *to her face* that she is the flavor-of-the-week, to be discarded when the next young thing comes along. Unless you have no plans to see her again until after the divorce, I would not suggest it.

If the wedding was less than a year or so ago, you can say

> This is my Uncle Archie's new wife.

Otherwise, just stick to

> This is my Uncle Archie's wife.

Answer (score 3):

The current in the sentence doesn't seem necessary. The third party you are introducing your Uncle Archie to needn't know that information.

Answer (score 3):

Technically and grammatically right but socially awkward. Simply stick to "This is my Uncle Archie's wife."

If the third party you are introducing your uncle's wife to is someone an acquaintance they will enquire which one. Then you can probably say third or current one but you don't need to announce that to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

It would generally be considered rude to say this, as it seems that you are suggesting she will not be his wife for much longer. It is fine to simply say wife, because any previous wives are ex-wives, and this will be the general understanding of whoever you are introducing her to.

Comment: A summary of the comments but a valid post nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

If I was explaining to someone who the people in the family photo album are, then I might refer to her as Archie's current or latest wife. But in a social situation it would be impolite to bring attention to her being one of multiple wives if it wasn't strictly necessary.